# The application runs in the debugger mode, the debugger won't connect

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

My Android application somehow stopped to pay any attention to the breakpoints. I have added the

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

to the manifest. So now it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.innodigital.iptv.PackVideo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_label" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="PackVideo"
              android:label="@string/app_label"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="ChannelsListActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="ServerSetActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I have returned debugger timeout to the default 3000 ms.

I had restarted the device I am working with and the PC.

Nothing helps.

I have installed [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 11 and run the debugging there. Same reaction: no stops on breakpoints.

Where should I look else? Beforehand grateful.

Edit: It seems debugger won't connect. Even after I am setting the timeout to 10 seconds.

```
Attempting to connect debugger to 'net.innodigital.iptv.PackVideo' on port 8615
```

waits forever.

Comment: More information is needed explain what you are trying to debug.

Comment: What exactly you want to know?

Comment: What are you trying to debug. If its a built in application, you have to attach to the process.

Comment: Are you even attaching to the process? This is required in order for it to be able to be debuggable.

Comment: It is the application I was debugging every day 100 time for a month

Comment: No, debugger is waiting to connect and never connects. I had checked it and added this to the question 5 min ago already, sorry

Comment: This sounds like a tool problem then. Not an application problem.

Comment: If the app Eclipse gives me:Attempting to connect debugger to 'net.innodigital.iptv.PackVideo' on port 8615 and keeps mum surely it is the problem of the tool

Comment: @Gangnus questions don't get down voted for being difficult to answer, they get down voted for being poor questions.

Comment: It's good that you solved your question, but notice how the two critical pieces of information, "yesterday I have exported apk" and "two instances of the application struggled for the same port", you never mentioned in your original post? How did you expect anyone to answer your question when you never gave us the information you needed yourself?

Comment: @vascowhite I put in this question everything I thought could be applicable to the situation. If I knew that something is relevant, I would put it in the question. To punish a person for not knowing while he is aksing for knowledge... Hmmm I am not swearing not because it is forbidden, but because I don't know enough strong swears. If you see that question is bad, *say* what could be improved.

Comment: @DourHighArch If I would know that installing apk from SD is important, I would say about it, too. That struggling is only my thought. Later thought and now I think, not so good one. Now I have a better explanation. See in my answer. BTW, if I knew exactly what info I need, I would already have the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ho! It was very interesting. It happened, that yesterday I have exported [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) and installed it on the same device. And it seems, that that instance of the application didn't let the instance from PC (being newly debugged) to be installed into the device. But it started to run itself instead. And the debugger couldn't connect the old APK with the new (even if almost the same) code. That explained:

1. Why *both* IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse couldn't connect the debugger to the application
2. Why, after uninstalling of the application from the device, the debugging launch went OK.

What interesting conclusions could be made of it:

1. We should never mix the different kinds of installations (from PC, from SD). Uninstall one, than install the other.
2. The installations from PC and from SD behave differently. That could cause other unwanted effects. We should be aware of it.

Comment: @pPeter Mortensen. Thank you for your edition. Only I don't understand why I see sometimes the changes of a paragraph into an absolutely same paragraph? is it a bug?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the device, adding this to the manifest could help.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>
```

Comment: You can also try restarting ADB, and if this is not working, maybe placing: Debug.waitForDebugger() will help.

Comment: +1 for the sole attempt to help. I found the other solution, as you can see, but thank you anyway.